# How to test angularJS in a java web application

Tags: java, angularjs, testing

Can I ask what is the best approach for testing an angular application, which is being delivered as a java web application.  I am using jersey/jax-rs, and some spring config, and am not using node.js which I can see some testing suites require for TDD.

i

Answer (score 0):

If you were referring to `protractor` (https://github.com/angular/protractor), you can use it even if your web app isn't a node.js app. Doesn't really matter, as it tests your app by driving a web browser and doesn't require integration with the backend stack

As for the backend, you just use whatever you were using to test your Jersey app

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link - this is a node.js application.  I am not using node.js.  I have jersey/JAX-RS config in my java web app - so it has to run in a servlet container.  my app has to run in tomcat etc so java and spring gets bootsrapped.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS team recommends Karma. It is ok for both Unit testing and E2E testing.
Good starting point for you is [Karma website](http://karma-runner.github.io) and [Full-Spectrum Testing with AngularJS and Karma](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html)

Comment: I am not using node.js.  I have jersey/JAX-RS config in my java web app so it has to run in a servlet container.  Karma is a node.js application, my app has to run in tomcat etc so java and spring gets bootsrapped.

Comment: Client side is independent from RESTful web services. It does not matter how server side is implemented. Anyway it is better to write angular unit tests using Jasmine(http://jasmine.github.io/). You can run unit test directly from command line using karma. If you do not want to install NodeJS at all then you can try other runners (for example https://github.com/wgroeneveld/jasmine-junit-runner)

Answer (score 0):

Spring now has a good example at https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js
The example uses jasmine but karma or protractor could also be used.

And another good example - https://dzone.com/articles/java-maven-angularjs-seed